# CurrentCulture in Silverlight4 and DataGrids

Tags: silverlight, wcf, datagrid

I having problems with DataGrid component: It shows en-US date-format (mm/dd/yyyy), but the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is pt-BR (dd/MM/yyyy).

Stranger is the fact that datetime is show in pt-BR when edit it: [image](http://img7.mediafire.com/6b12e293c8b986af9ef724abeef0e0475g.jpg)

I can just do a IValueConverter to show it as a string (tested and worked, using CurrentCulture), but then I lost the date edition...

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Are these autogenerated columns or are you creating them? Can you post that?

Comment: Is autogenerated, the source is a WCF service that returns objects with System.DateTime properties, and the string-format is {0:G\}

Everything else is by default, made no changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this thread](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/188004/431347.aspx) for a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks, I did not find that thread ^^'

Well, another reason why I fell silverlight will end as WPF...

Comment: "End" as WPF? Whatever do you mean? :) WPF is quite successful, I feel. But maybe this is not the place for such arguably subjective opinions.